# read an array environment variable in c++ using getenv on linux

Tags: c++

i have an an environment variable which is an array. i need to get and set it from my c++ application. how can I get this using a std::map. i am able to do this in tcl easily using array set and array get.
tcl example:

```
 set myenvarray(key1) val1
 set myenvarray(key2) val2
 set env(myarray) [array get myenvarray]
```

Thanks

Comment: Start by just getting the variable using `getenv` and see what you actually get. Then you can start thinking about parsing that string into a map. In short, unless you search and find someone who has already done it, there's no easy ready-made way to do it.

Comment: Anything you have done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have following format of your environment variable: `[key1,val1][key2,val2]`. You can get the content of your variable using `getenv("varname")`.

Then you can use a simple Regex to iterate over the key-value pairs and add them to a map.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string env = "[key1,val1][key2,val2]"; //getenv("varname");

    regex rx("\\[([^,]+),([^\\]]+)\\]");
    map<string, string> res;

    for(regex_iterator<string::iterator> it(env.begin(), env.end(), rx), end; it != end; it++)
        res[(*it)[1]] = (*it)[2];

    for(auto it : res) 
        cout << it.first << " = " << it.second << endl;

    return 0;
}
```